# How to do the count operation using tuple criteria restriction during run time i got 412 error code

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, criteria, boot

> [image: Output Response in swagger-ui]

```
if (searchFilter.getSortType() == SortType.asc) {
      orderList.add(builder.asc(root.get("count")));
   } else {
     orderList.add(builder.desc(root.get("count")));
}
```

I want the JSON output response as per the count based output. I need to do aggregate function during run time.

In the above program I passed `root.get("count");` Here instead of count I need to pass any one of the aggregate function like `sum, avg,min,max, count` like that.

How I can pass run time aggregate function using `hibernate Tuple` criteria restriction?

Comment: Your question is about an error code you got from a service, but doesn't say anything about the service itself, even what service it is - that's the first thing to look at and ask questions about.  The code you are using to build your query might not even be relevant